# Getting the id of a model from a button in Django

Tags: python, django

I currently have a template set up so that it loops through all of my menu items with a button that correspond to a post request in my views.py

```
          <td>
          {% for menu_items in menu %}
            {{ menu_items.Menu_name }}
          {% endfor %}  
        </td>
        <td>
          {% for menu_desc in menu %}
              {{ menu_desc.Menu_Desc }}
          {% endfor %}
        </td>
        <form method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <th><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Add To Cart" name="add">. 
        </th>
        </form>
```

In my views file I have a if statement that tries to get the id of the model that was clicked.
However, i'm only able to get the Query Set and not the specific ID of the model.

```
def ordering(request):
     latest_order = Order.objects.all()
     menu = Menu.objects.all()
     if 'add' in request.POST:
        user_order = Order.objects.get(name='')
        print(menu.id)
     return render(request, 'users/ordering.html', {'title':'Ordering', 'latest_order': latest_order, 'menu':menu})
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with queryset, whatever is returned has a primary key and not id as you would occasionally think, therefore use

```
item.pk instead of item.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the id of QuerySet, in the situation, you can treat the QuerySet like an iterable, try to print this way:

```
menu = Menu.objects.all()
print([item.id for item in menu])
```